# Construct a probability function on the operator monotone functions, $g(t)=t g(t^{-1})$, fitting certain values

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, operator-theory, matrix-analysis, quantum-mechanics

To immediately pose the question of interest to us, without first expanding upon its (quantum-information-theoretic) origin—we seek a univariate function $f$, for which we have the ("two-qubit separability")  probability results $f(\frac{1+t}{2})=\frac{25}{341} =0.0733138$ and 
$f(\sqrt{t}) =1 -\frac{256}{27 \pi^2}=0.0393251$. (Also, at least in a limiting sense, $f(\frac{2 t}{1+t}) =0.$)

The possible arguments of $f$ in which we are interested are the members of  the (infinite) class of operator monotone functions (of $t$) . (Theorem 7 of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594002118  tells us that such functions $g(t)$ satisfy the relation $g(t)=t g(t^{-1})$.)

Other—than the three already given ($\frac{1+t}{2}$ (the minimal), $\sqrt{t}$ and $\frac{2 t}{1+t}$ (the maximal))--members of the infinite class of operator monotone functions for which we have (2004) calculations (but only of a numerical nature, accurate to at most four decimal places, we believe) are for $f(\frac{t^{(t-1)}}{e})  \approx 0.0609965$, $f(\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)^2) \approx 0.0503391$ and $f(\frac{(t-1)}{\log{t}}) \approx .0346801$. 
(Table II, p. 14 in https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308037), and also $f(\frac{1+6 t +t^2}{4 +4 t}) \approx 0.0475438$ (Table I there).

For background on the first value ($\frac{25}{341}$) of $f$ given, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09889, and for the second ($1-\frac{256}{27 \pi^2}$), see eq. (87) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01973  .

Comment: What is $t$ in (say) $f(\frac{1+t}{2})=\frac{25}{341}$? Also, what do you mean by "function/functions $f(t)$"? Is $t$ the argument of a function $f$? Then the function is $f$, not $f(t)$.

Comment: Per comment of Iosif Pinelis, changed $f(t)$ to $f$ at outset of question. Hopefully, the intent of the question is clear.

Comment: It's still unclear what $t$ is. It is not specified in your post by quantifiers "for all" or "there exist(s)" or in any other way.

Comment: Actually it is only clear that you are looking for a function $f$. You should kindly add a definition of its domain, a definition of its co-domain, and a list of properties you want it to have. (Each point in unambiguous way, otherwise the there will be a bunch of possible interpretations!)

Comment: Theorem 7 of https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379594002118 tells us (changing $f$ there to $g$ here) that operator monotone functions $g(t)$ satisfy the relation $g(t)=t g(t^{-1})$--as can be checked with $\frac{1+t}{2}$, and the other examples. (So, maybe I should have set up the whole problem using $g$, not $f$.)

Comment: Thanks, Pietro Majer! Well, certaintly the domain is the set of operator monotone functions--that is those for which $g(t)=t g(t^{-1})$--and the range is $[0,\frac{25}{341}]$. Otherwise, I certainly don't have definite specifications.  What are the "possible interpretations"? (I am clearly "fishing" here with no idea, really at all, what the nature of the sought function would be, if it even exists in some sense or other.)

Comment: Is it acceptable, for example, to declare those values of $f$ that you want to be as you want and declare all other values of $f$ to be zero?

Comment: Well, the class of operator monotone functions is nondenumerably infinite--and I know at most three function values exactly. I was thinking of a function that would be able to give the values/probabilities for any member of the class.

Comment: Isn't $\log t$ operator monotone? That doesn't seem to satisfy that relation on $g$.

Comment: J. E. Pascoe--if $t>0$ and $g(t)=\frac{(t-1)}{\log{t}}$, then $g(t)=t g(t^{-1})$, as per the operator monotone relation indicated in the title.

Comment: J. E. Pascoe--I guess I didn't answer your question. $\log{t}$ clearly doesn't fit the titular relation employed by Denes Petz in his several papers pertaining to the matter. I'll have to re-examine them somewhat more closely, to see the origin of this specific definition.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater, what was the goal here? That is, the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the question J. E. Pascoe! I was conceiving of a (I guess) "functional"  that would map the operator monotone functions into the values (25/341,...) of the "separability probabilities"--that is the ratio of the volume of the separable "two-qubit" states to the total (separable and entangled) states. In this conception, the states would be endowed with the metric corresponding (by the work of Petz-Sudar in J. Math. Phys.) to the specific operator monotone function. Happy to try to clarify further. But probably a "very tall order" for a "functional" to fulfill. "Pie-in-the-sky"?

Comment: @PaulB.Slater, it might be useful to consider the fact that operator monotone functions are exactly self maps of the upper half plane, and therefore have nice integral representations. In Peter Lax "Functional Analysis" book, I think these are called "Nevanlinna representations." To make a long story short, this would make your function $f$ depend on a real number $a,$ a nonnegative $b$ and a positive measure on the real line $\mu.$

Comment: Thanks for the comment--will consider what you suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Well, "to start the ball rolling", let us assume the desired function is the second-degree polynomial
\begin{equation}
f(x) =a_0 +a_1 x +a_2 x^2.
\end{equation}
Then, we can achieve the three target exact results $f(\frac{1+t}{2})=\frac{25}{341}$, $f(\sqrt{t}) =1 -\frac{256}{27 \pi^2}$ and  $f(\frac{2 t}{1+t}) =0$, by taking
\begin{equation}
a_0=-\frac{2 \sqrt{t} \left(27 \pi ^2 \left(682 t^{3/2}+341 t^2+582 t+682
   \sqrt{t}+341\right)-87296 \left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)^2 (t+1)\right)}{9207 \pi ^2
   \left(\sqrt{t}-1\right)^4 \left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)^2},
\end{equation} 
\begin{equation}
a_1=\frac{27 \pi ^2 (t (341 t+1946)+341)-87296 (t (t+6)+1)}{9207 \pi ^2
   \left(\sqrt{t}-1\right)^4 \sqrt{t}},
\end{equation} 
and
\begin{equation}
a_2=-\frac{2 (t+1) \left(27 \pi ^2 \left(341 t+632 \sqrt{t}+341\right)-87296
   \left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)^2\right)}{9207 \pi ^2 \left(\sqrt{t}-1\right)^4
   \left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)^2 \sqrt{t}},
\end{equation} 
giving us that the second-degree polynomial $f(x)$ is obtainable by dividing
\begin{equation}
\left(27 \pi ^2 \left(682 t^{3/2}+341 t^2+t (582-682 x)+\sqrt{t} (682-1264 x)-682
   x+341\right)-87296 \left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)^2 (t-2 x+1)\right) (t (x-2)+x)
\end{equation}
by
\begin{equation}
9207 \pi ^2 \left(\sqrt{t}-1\right)^4 \left(\sqrt{t}+1\right)^2 \sqrt{t}.
\end{equation}

Our four other target values are only numerical and perhaps accurate to only 3-4 decimal places. Rationalizing one of them, 0.0346801, we  added $f(\frac{t-1}{\log{t}})=\frac{347}{10000}$ to our set of equations, and obtained a further (larger) solution.

In this proof-of-principle exercise, one could take $f(x)$ to be other than polynomial in nature--rational functions,...

However, perhaps in my original conception of the problem I was thinking that $t$ would not be present in the expression of the desired function $f(x)$, as it certainly is in the coefficients of the second-degree polynomial given above.